# How can I disable .onclick for element's children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$("#one_to_many").on("click", function(){
    $( this ).html('<form action="demo_form.asp">\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="like"> کامنت ها<br>\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="comment" checked> لایک ها<br>\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="friend" checked> دوستان<br>\
      <input type="button" value="رسم گراف">\
     </form>');
});
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one_to_many">click</div>
```

As you see I cannot trigger those checkbox. In other word, I cannot mark a checkbox option as selected or deselect it.

How can I make it available?

Comment: Try to use `.one('click')` [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: you can unbind click as there is no use after one click as well `$("#one_to_many").unbind("click");`

Comment: @vp_arth: Why do I keep forgetting about `one`?! :-)

Comment: We forget all rare used things..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:

One is to remove the click handler once you've populated the div with the checkboxes:

```js
$("#one_to_many").on("click", function(){
    // ------vvvvvvvvvvvvv
    $( this ).off("click").html('<form action="demo_form.asp">\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="like"> کامنت ها<br>\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="comment" checked> لایک ها<br>\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="friend" checked> دوستان<br>\
      <input type="button" value="رسم گراف">\
     </form>');
});
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one_to_many">click</div>
```

(Or as [vp_arth points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931652/how-can-i-disable-onclick-for-elements-children/41931709#comment71043689_41931652), just use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) to hook it up instead of `on` — I tend to forget about `one`!)

Another is to check the `event.target` within the click handler and ignore the event if it's a checkbox:

```js
$("#one_to_many").on("click", function(event){  // ***
    if ($(event.target).is("input[type=checkbox]")) {
        return;
    }
    $( this ).html('<form action="demo_form.asp">\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="like"> کامنت ها<br>\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="comment" checked> لایک ها<br>\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="friend" checked> دوستان<br>\
      <input type="button" value="رسم گراف">\
     </form>');
});
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one_to_many">click</div>
```

...but if you use `label` elements (you aren't, but I'd recommend it) that could get tricky. You could only process the click if `event.target` *is* the `div`:

(I've added `label`s to this to illustrate.)

```js
$("#one_to_many").on("click", function(event){  // ***
    if (event.target != this) {
        return;
    }
    $( this ).html('<form action="demo_form.asp">\
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="like"> کامنت ها</label><br>\
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="comment" checked> لایک ها</label><br>\
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="friend" checked> دوستان</label><br>\
      <input type="button" value="رسم گراف">\
     </form>');
});
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one_to_many">click</div>
```

Comment: just wondering why this kind of scenario happens, this is kinda weird :D

Comment: @Roljhon It happens because events propagate upwards through the DOM tree, starting at the original element and ending at the document. Click on the checkbox and you get a click event registered for each element between the checkbox and the document itself. And, since the checkbox is inside the DIV, your click event handler to initialise the DIV's content to that HTML will run again.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one more solution with a shorten script:

```js
$("#one_to_many").on("click", function(){
    $("#one_to_many form").toggle();
});
$("#one_to_many form").on("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

#one_to_many form {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one_to_many">click
<form action="demo_form.asp">
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="like"> کامنت ها<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="comment" checked> لایک ها<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="friend" checked> دوستان<br>
      <input type="button" id="cls_btn" value="رسم گراف">
     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `one()` , This method attaches one or more event handlers for the selected elements, and specifies a function to run when the event occurs.

When using the one() method, the event handler function is only run ONCE for each element.

```js
$("#one_to_many").one("click", function(e){
    $( this ).html('<form action="demo_form.asp">\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="like"> کامنت ها<br>\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="comment" checked> لایک ها<br>\
      <input type="checkbox" name="graph" value="friend" checked> دوستان<br>\
      <input type="button" value="رسم گراف">\
     </form>');
});
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="one_to_many">click</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```